# MySQL select result save into c# variable

Tags: c#, mysql

Can you please check my code and answer me how can i save a mysql select result into a c# string?

```
try
{
    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
    string selectCmd = "SELECT * FROM  TabelaUtilizatori";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectCmd, _dbConnect.getConnection());
    string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    label2.Text = result;
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

or maybe this way?

```
            using (_dbConnect.getConnection())
             {
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
                  "SELECT NAME FROM TABELAUTILIZATORI WHERE EMAIL = 'asdjaa@asdka.com'"        
              _dbConnect.getConnection());


            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                while (reader.Read())
                {
                 label2.Text=
                }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

thanks a lot !

Comment: This would be more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Zarathuztra I don't think so, the OP just does not know how iterate through the results.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I can see that being the case. Fair enough.

Comment: label1.text =  with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,You can use ExecuteReader() for this..

```
        try
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            string selectCmd = "SELECT * FROM  TabelaUtilizatori";

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectCmd, _dbConnect.getConnection());
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string ColumnName = (string)reader["ColumnName"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: yes, you can do it,  replace ColumnName as Name and change select query

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a different api.
ExecuteReader is more appropriate here and it will allow you to iterate through all results.
An example can be found here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Note that there is no single result with this, there are multiple columns and multiple records, so these don't fit in a single string.
Unless you want something like select count(*)

Also note that it is not considered good practice to have code like this
select * from ... it is better to specify which columns you really need. Your application will be less likely to break if the datamodel changes.

Also read about using parameters in a query :

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Comment: I want like this : SELECT NAME WHERE EMAIL IS = 'asda@asda.com'

        using (_dbConnect.getConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
                  "SELECT NAME FROM TABELAUTILIZATORI WHERE EMAIL = 'dontzapone@yahoo.com'",
                  _dbConnect.getConnection());
                

                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

               
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        
                    }
              
                reader.Close();
            }