# how to add result from mysql to label or string variable? in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to add mysql query result to a variable of type string or label. 
My query SQL example:
"select idCat from MyDatabase.CategoryTable where CategoryName="movies".
Mysql query returns only one result. 
What variables (objects) i should be use in addition MyConnection and MySQLcommand to do this. I would be grateful for any help. 
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string.

```
MySqlDataReader reader = null;
            string selectCmd = "select idCat from MyDatabase.CategoryTable where CategoryName="movies";
```

[Save Query result in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857165/save-query-result-in-a-variable)

[MySQL select result save into c# variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062683/mysql-select-result-save-into-c-sharp-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You can use executescalar method MySqlcommand object.

```
string sql = @"select idCat from MyDatabase.CategoryTable where CategoryName="movies"";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (result != null)
{
 string r = (string)result; 
}
```

refer this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html)